# how to for loop with two conditions with a list in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently I have this

```
for device in variables['devices']:
    do something
```

I want to run the above loop for only 10 times can I do something like this?

```
for device in variables['variable'] and range(1,10):
     do something
```

and again want to loop again from 11, till end of list in `variables['devices']`
How do I approach this?

Comment: If `variables['devices']` is a list, `for device in variables['devices'][:10]: `, then `for device in variables['devices'][10:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `variables['devices']` is a list, for device in `variables['devices'][:10]:` , then for device in `variables['devices'][10:]`

This answer is from comments by [SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7711444/sam)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to avoid nested loops:

```
count = 0
for device in variables['devices']:
    count += 1
    if count <= 10:
        do something
    else:
        do something else
```

Comment: Orginal comment to the question actually solved my problem,